# Node js read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) | Websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am created chat application using `Websocket`.In this I am uploading image to `room`. When I upload Image I will end up with following error and it creates new connection for the all the client the Room.
Error coming from below function.

```
connection.on("error",function(err){
      console.log('error',err.code)
      console.log(err)
  })
```

following log message

```
server listening to port 3001
new user connected hi                   #user 1 (room1) he is going to upload image
new user connected hi                    #user 2(room1)
error ECONNRESET
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
user disconnected Socket Error: read ECONNRESET               # user1(room1) disconnected
error ECONNRESET
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
user disconnected Socket Error: read ECONNRESET           #user2(room1) disconnected
new user connected hi                               #user 1 (room1)
new user connected hi                                #user 2(room1)
```

two clients are listening to port 3000 : (react)

**Client Code : App.js**

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.connection =  null;
    this.appName = "Chat-App";
    this.SERVER = "http://localhost:3001/";
}




 componentDidMount(){

    this.connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3001');
}





handleImageUpload = async(event,photo)=>{
 
  event.preventDefault()
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("photo", photo);

  fetch(this.SERVER+'uploads', {method: "POST", body: formData})
  .then((response)=>{
    console.log('response from server',response)
    this.connection.send(this.createJsonString("image_upload",photo.name,this.state.activeRoom));
  })
```

**Server side**

```
const UPLOAD_LOC = './../client/public/'

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req,file,callback) {
      callback(null, UPLOAD_LOC);
    },
    filename: function(req,file,callback) {
      callback(null,file.originalname);
    }
  })

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })


app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
})

var server = require('http').createServer(app);



app.post('/uploads',upload.single("photo"),function(req,res){
   res.send({error:'false',message:'image uploaded'});
  
})
```

**server side event handler**

```
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    console.log('new user connected','hi')
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);    

  connection.on('message', function(message) {        
    const json = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data)
    let userId = json.userId;
    let body = json.body;
    
    switch(json.meta){ 
        case 'image_upload':

            fs.readFile(UPLOAD_LOC+body,function(err,buf){ //here body contains file name
             if(!err){
                 userList = getRoomUserList(json.roomName);//get the all the user from the room
                 for(i = 0;i<userList.length;i++){
                     let user = userList[i];
                         getSocketId(user).send(createJsonString('image_upload',user,buf.toString('base64'),json.roomName))
                     }
                    
                 }else{
                     console.log('is this error',err)
                 }

             })

            break;

        }
```

Please help me ... **Thanks in advance ..!**

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question . Here I what did is I am uploading image to react default folder `public` this is the problem.

I changed upload directory now it is working fine.